# Sharepoint Reporting Options

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports

My manager requested some reporting based off of a SharePoint site that was created to be used as a support portal for our team.

I originally created an Excel spreadsheet with a data connection to the SharePoint site, but because he's running Office 2010, some of the graphs and queries that were running didn't work for him. He told me that he believes that SharePoint has some innate/built-in reporting capabilities, and suggested I reach out to you for advice on how to access them.

Does SharePoint actually have built-in reporting? Or is Excel the best option?

Comment: Reports of site usage or reports with data from lists and libraries?

Comment: Data from lists, in particular (hopefully able to be summarized and/or curated in some way).

Answer (score 1):

There is some basic built-in reporting at the Site and Site Collection levels. 1) Under Site Settings, Site Administration, Popularity Trends. 2) Site Settings, Site Collection Administration, Popularity and Search Reports.

Answer (score 1):

There are several report solutions based on your report complexity.

[Power Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456880.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SSRS for SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068(v=sql.110).aspx)

Other front-end report libraries like [Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm but a minion of a much larger organization, so my account doesn't have access to link Sharepoint to SSRS (I already tried), so that option is a no-go. Option 2 also looks like I would have to be a SharePoint administrator, so that's not possible either. :( Thanks for the answer, though.